# Mocking with functionality

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am very new to Mockito, please let me know if I'm on the right track. I'm trying to mock method functionality using Mockito.

[sscce](http://sscce.org)

```
public SUTclass {
    private final DependencyInjectedObj dep; // already successfully mocked
    private int statefulInteger;
    private int otherInteger;

    public int doSomething() {
        return otherInteger + dep.doMath(statefulInteger);
    }
}
```

Right now, `dep` is mocked... but `dep.doMath` always returns `0`. In production, `dep` is stateful - no way to avoid it. In production, a different thread updates its state in real time. `dep.doMath` does some funky calculations depending on the state right now. You could imagine that production functionality might look at a thermometer and do something with it's temerature, and `doSomething` gives a realtime status based on that temperature.

In my test, though, I'd like to have `dep.doMath` have this functionality (which is a sufficient approximation for a unit test):

```
public int doMath(int input) {
    return SOMECONSTANT * input;
}
```

I suppose I could create a Mock implementation of `DependencyInjectedObj` and use that, but that seems to defeat the purpose of using Mockito and the `when` syntax. What should I do?

Comment: You can use `thenReturn` (or whatever it's called, `andReturn`? Don't recall.) to return whatever you want--what specifically is the issue? Also, mocking isn't *always* the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, what you want is `doAnswer()`. It allows you to execute arbitrary code when a mock invocation is called:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Integer>() {
  public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
      Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
      int i = (int)args[0];
      return i * CONSTANT;
  }
}).when(dep.doMath(any(Integer.class));
```

I do consider `doAnswer` a bit evil, though. Generally `thenReturn(CONSTANT)` is sufficient for most unit tests. If you're going to verify the result of this method call, then you're testing the wrong class -- the point of mocking your dependencies is you don't much care about their operation.

Comment: Well, I want to verify that `doSomething` gives different answers based on different values of `statefulInteger`. Except the only thing that `statefulInteger` does in the `doSomething` method is get passed to `dep`.

Comment: That is what I mean by you are testing the wrong class, based on your description. `doSomething` performs addition based on the result of the dependent class. Just `thenReturn(CONSTANT)` from the dependency and assert that the result of `doSomething` is the input plus the known constant.

Comment: In other words, `doSomething`s job is to perform addition. That is all a proper unit test should cover. The vagaries of `dep.doMath` is for another test to cover.

Comment: I see what you're saying and I'm almost convinced. My last sticking point is that if `dep.doMath` returns, say, `0`, none of the values returned by `doSomething` will make any sense (or bear any similarity) to what they do in production. Does that matter? Like I said, very new to Mockito and TDD.

Comment: It really sounds like you care more about the outcome of `dep.doMath` and `doSomething` is really a distraction here. The contract of `doSomething` appears to be "Add `otherInteger` to the result of `dep.DoMath(statefulInteger)`. Mocking that call with any known result (0, 1, N) will let you assert that doSomething does indeed perform addition. Anything else is out of scope here.

Comment: Ironic. This discussion helped me find a bug in `SUTclass` a lot sooner than I would have otherwise. Thanks TomG!